# Camera keeps cutting to black and I cant stop it

Tags: camera

Basically been playing around with a blender template and the creator set the camera to cut to black at the end, but I want to add more to scene, but the camera is stuck just "off" basically. He uses this to "stutter" (like flashing to black repeatedly) the camera also and I would also like to get rid of that if possible.

Comment: Hi, your description is pretty vague so perhaps link to said template at least, thanks. I don't think it is doing exactly what you just described.

Comment: Sure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWyCdozzqKo&feature=youtu.be. File is at http://www.mediafire.com/file/15ac8n0d5ngqnx0/NewNow2.blend

Comment: See how it cuts out to black at the 6 second mark? It does it after the scene ends also, even after adding more frames in.

Answer (score 0):

The cut to black is caused by an **Alpha Over Node** in the *Compositor*.

At frame 207 there's a keyframe for the node's *Factor* to 1.

[image: Alpha Over]

Comment: Thank you! Okay I don't know how to edit it so it will stop? I tried deleting it and that didn't help or maybe I am looking at the wrong thing. I deleted the tiny F_206 and a couple of those green lines.

Comment: @MasonMacony You can delete the keyframe by going to frame 207, right-clicking on the field `Fac: 1.000` in the *Alpha Over* node and selecting *“Delete Keyframe”*.